# How to run some piece of code in background, after a function returns in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make a background process which will compress a combination of files. I have a python project which have flask API. I want that when a flask API receives request, compression should start and API return should not wait for end of compression thread.

I have this bunch of code but it waits for the time for completion

```
@server.route("/api/dummy/zip", methods=['GET'])
def compress_file():
    print("zipping starts at", time.time())
    file_path = ""
    file_name = ""
    comObj = compression_handler.CompressionThread()
    comObj.__int__(file_name, file_path)
    logging.info("compression starts")
    print("zipping end at", time.time())
    return "zipping has took "
```

and compression_handler python file :

```
import zipfile
import os
from os.path import basename
import threading
import threading
from Main import logging


class CompressionThread:

def __int__(self, file_name, file_path):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.compress, args=(['/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/jdk-8u171-macosx-x64.dmg', '/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/resume-nirmal-sarswat.pdf'],))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    logging.info('thread has started, in progress')

def compress(self, file_list):
    print("running thread in list")
    try:
        zip_path = '/Users/nirmalsarswat/Documents/newone.zip'
        print(zip_path)
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for files in file_list:
            zip_file.write(files, basename(files))
        zip_file.close()
        logging.info("compression of files is done !!!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception occured during compression %s" % e)
```

Following code output is like this (in console debugging)

```
> Zipping starts at xxxxx
> running thread in list \n
> compression of files is done !!! \n
> thread has started, in progress
> compression starts
> zipping end at xxxxxx
```

Comment: Why do you have an [`__int__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) method? That's for returning an integer value for your object. And it shouldn't take any parameters besides `self`  And you don't call it with `obj.__int__`, you just do `int(obj)`.

Comment: Also, what is the `CompressionThread` class even for? You don't store any attributes on it, you don't call any methods on it. Why not just have a `compress` function, and a `compress_on_thread` function that creates a `Thread(target=compress, args=[whatever])` and starts it?

Comment: Ok good point @abarnert, but my concern is about actual background process which runs in back and don't give a wait to API to send response back. How can I do that?

Comment: Finally, the logs you're posting can't come from this code. For example, your output has `Zipping` with a capital `Z`, but your code has only `zipping` with a lowercase `z`. And there's no way printing `"running thread in list"` could print out `running thread in list \n`. And so on. We can't debug your code if you show us something kind of like your code and output but not actually your code and output.

Comment: I added this for actually tell the sequence of code execution, not intuition behind log and all. Can you tell what I need to know @abarnert

Comment: There are many things that could cause this: calling `thread.run()` instead of `thread.start()`, passing `self.compress()` instead of `self.compress`, doing a `join` or a `with` somewhere… If you showed us an actual [mcve] I could rule those out, but you haven't.

Comment: Ok, I will take care of it @abarnert

Comment: @abarnert I guess start is better than run, see here https://www.quora.com/In-a-thread-what-is-the-difference-between-run-and-start

Comment: `start` isn't "better than `run`". They're different methods that do different things. And using `run` when you meant `start` is an example of the kinds of common errors made by people who don't want to read the docs, or understand their code, or post the same code in their question that they're actually running. That's why I mentioned it as one of the many things that could cause this problem.

Comment: ok thank you @abarnert